# Logarithm of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm currently studying Complex Analysis.
However I have a question about the exponential of a complex number that's blowing up my mind.

I have this statement and I want you to clarify me, please:

" The exponential function applies $\mathbb{C}$ to  $\mathbb{C}$ except the origin. However this function is not bijective. Every point $w \neq 0$ is the image of an infinity of points $z$.  "

I think I don't really get this... Is it because $e^x e^{iy}=e^x e^{i(y+2k\pi)}$ (same module and the argument is the same in less that a multiple of $2k\pi$)
Because this seems to be the only way...

The next statement also makes me confused

"It we restrain the domain to a band $Im(z) \in [y, y+2\pi[$ we will have a bijection"

Ok this makes sense if my previous conclusion is indeed correct. Because the only way to complex numbers have the same image under the exponential function is for them to not have the same argument, am I right? 
However what exactly is the image of this band in the complex plane? All of it except the origin?

Thanks!

Comment: The band for the restricted domain should be a half-open interval $[y,y+2\pi)$ or $(y,y+2\pi].$

Comment: You're absolutely right, corrected

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  In just about everything.  e^z is more or less periodic so there are infinite solutions to e^z = w.  As if z is a solution so is z+i2k\pi.  But if we restrict it to a band,  modulo i2pi then e^z:band -> C/0 is a bijection.